# Same file , same filesize but two different memory sizes , Why?

Tags: c, file-io

```
FILE *fp;

short *originalUnPacked;
short *unPacked;

int fileSize;

fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
fseek (fp , 0 , SEEK_END);
fileSize = ftell (fp);
rewind (fp);

originalUnPacked = (short*) malloc (sizeof(char)*fileSize);
unPacked = (short*) malloc (sizeof(char)*fileSize);

printf ( "The UnPacked  : %d ", unPacked);
printf ( "The Original UnPacked  : %d ", originalUnPacked);
```

// The above print statement prints two different values ,my question is Why ?

Comment: `malloc` returns a pointer to newly allocated memory (or NULL if a failure occurs), not the size of the allocated memory block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be passing short* to printf.  It expects a simple short, right?

If you print a short*, you're not getting the size, you're getting the address of where that memory is.